# DIV on hover - make it can be hovered through and change it's opacity, without blinking

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ok, I have dynamically created `div` for a legend on a graph with class `.legend`.

User must be able to hover on graph lines (to see it's values), but they cannot do it through legend `div` which is over the graph.

[image]

I tried with `pointer-events:none` like this:

```
$("#placeholder").on({ 
    mouseenter: 
       function() 
       { 
        $(".legend").css("opacity", "0.2");
        $(".legend").css("pointer-events", "none");
       }, 
    mouseleave: 
       function() 
       { 
        $(".legend").css("opacity", "1");
        $(".legend").css("pointer-events", "auto");
       } 
   }, ".legend"
);
```

... and it works BUT, it blinks on every mouse move. Like every time I move pointer inside that `div`, whether I left `div` or not, it fires the event.

Is there any smoother way to do this?

The best way would be if I could, on first mouse enter, stop all mouse event listeners for that `div` except `mouseleave`, and after I leave `div` with pointer, it should attach again.

HTML code looks like this:

```
<div id="placeholder">

...

  <div class="legend">
    <div style="position: absolute; width: 114px; height: 48px; top: 17px; right: 19px; opacity: 0.85; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></div>
    <table style="position:absolute;top:17px;right:19px;;font-size:smaller;color:#545454">
      <tbody>
      <tr><td class="legendColorBox"><div style="border:1px solid #ccc;padding:1px"><div style="width:4px;height:0;border:5px solid darkorange;overflow:hidden"></div></div></td><td class="legendLabel">Temperature (C)</td></tr>
      <tr><td class="legendColorBox"><div style="border:1px solid #ccc;padding:1px"><div style="width:4px;height:0;border:5px solid blue;overflow:hidden"></div></div></td><td class="legendLabel">Minimum: 22.48 C</td></tr>
      <tr><td class="legendColorBox"><div style="border:1px solid #ccc;padding:1px"><div style="width:4px;height:0;border:5px solid red;overflow:hidden"></div></div></td><td class="legendLabel">Maximum: 24.85 C</td></tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

...

</div>
```

Any ideas, workarounds or advices would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show your html structure?

Comment: I edited, HTML code added.

Comment: It can be done by pure css. Wait.

Comment: The cause is that you're disabling hovering when hovered (put your cursor on the edge of [Jitter-Man's box](https://css-tricks.com/examples/CSS-Jitter/) to get a better visual). The legend is basically looping through "I'm hovered, so I become unhoverable, so I'm no longer hovered, so I'm hoverable".

Comment: Might I suggest instead of having the restore event be on `mouseleave` and using an `opacity` de-emphasize, you merely move the box between the upper-left and upper-right corners of its parent on `mouseenter`? It'll make it a bitch and a half to copy any text in the legend, but it'll completely solve your problem without running into the "hoverable area changes on hover" problem.

Comment: You mean like, moving this `.legend` `div` left and right on `mouseenter`?

Answer (score 1):

[Try in Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/harishkommuri/yh4tw5zz/3/).

Use following Script.

```
$("#placeholder").mouseenter(function() {
    $(".legend").animate({opacity: 0.25}, 600);
}).mouseleave(function() { 
    $(".legend").animate({opacity: 1}, 600);
});
```

Comment: OK, first problem is: I cannot hover THROUGH `.legend` `div` with your code (you never set `pointer-events` to `none`) and it starts fading to 0.2 when I put pointer on `#placeholder`, not on `.legend`. Second: `opacity` reverts to 1 only when I leave `#placeholder`, not `.legend` `div`. I hope you understood correctly what I'm trying to do...

Comment: Change selector and code as above. The code you expected for two different events. For mouse event of `#placeholder` and `.legend`. I think for that we need javascript. Wait for a while.

Comment: I'll try to combine something, we'll see. +1 for your useful answer.

Comment: Sorry for long delay. I have updated the code and fiddle link. Try it and let me know if you have more requirements.